# How can we create a new folder for our app where we can save the downloaded data

Tags: android, file, directory

I am developing an app that downloads the MP 3 files. I want to know how to create a new folder for my app that is visible in MY FILES of android and saves all the downloaded files into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean something like:

```
File theDirectory = new File("/sdcard/yourdir/");
theDirectory.mkdirs();
File outputFile = new File(theDirectory, filename);
```

Also, you probably want to use [Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory%28%29) and also add:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean with "MY FOLDERS"?
In general, you have to create a new File in an specific Folder:

```
File f = new File(getFilesDir(), "dateiname.mp3");
```

Comment: I mean that like every app has a folder in FILES of android and saves every data of that application in that folder. ((MY FILES) in samsung default app to save data of each app.)